# best approach of image versioning in yocto

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, versioning, yocto

What is the best approach for maintaining image versions in Yocto.

I mean suppose we build an image and given it to customer, in future we provided bug fixes to the customer..

How can we know which version of yocto image customer is using.. Is there any standard way to achieve this..

Thanks for your time. Appreciate your efforts..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are interested in [os-release](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/os-release/os-release.bb) recipe. This gives provision to add version details to the image. This recipe installs a file `/etc/os-release` in the target.

If you are interested in adding custom fields based on your application or purpose of the image, you can add extra fields in `OS_RELEASE_FIELDS` variable in `os-release.bbappend` in your custom layer. For example,

```
OS_RELEASE_FIELDS += "BUILD_VERSION"
BUG_FIXED_VERSION = "1.0.0-B1"
BUILD_VERSION = "${BUG_FIXED_VERSION}"
```

This adds the build id into `/etc/os-release` and you can increment the versions based on bug fix or new delivery.

Comment: You also need those 2 lines, otherwise the version will not be updated correctly:

`do_compile[nostamp] = "1"
do_install[nostamp] = "1"`