# About yocto /etc/os-release versioning

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, beagleboneblack

i try to implement /etc/os-release in  my beaglebone yocto
after some attempt in my google. i added following in my configuration files

local.conf

```
INHERIT += "image-buildinfo"

BUILD_ID = "${@time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime())}"

IMAGE_BUILDINFO_VARS = "DISTRO DISTRO_VERSION MACHINE IMAGE_NAME USER"
```

in os-release.bb

```
INHERIT += "image-buildinfo"

BUILD_ID = "${@time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime())}"

IMAGE_BUILDINFO_VARS = "DISTRO DISTRO_VERSION MACHINE IMAGE_NAME USER"
```

I was expecting /etc/os-release  or  /usr/lib/os-release build successfully upon bitbake run completely , but i don't see both of them in my images.

Am i missing anything?or i misinterpret on any concept?
Sorry for the rookies question, i am trying to exploring yocto

Comment: Possible better way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756726/best-approach-of-image-versioning-in-yocto/52760810#52760810

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be you still have to tell Yocto to *use* the os-release recipe?

With a os-release.bbappend you can modify the recipe that is part of [openembedded-core](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/28831/).
There are a few examples how to do at that webpage.  A good one is e.g. the one used in [meta-yoe](https://github.com/YoeDistro/meta-yoe/blob/master/recipes-core/os-release/os-release.bbappend).

But all this is just telling Yocto how to build the recipe.  You still have to tell Yocto to add it to your image.
This can be done in the local.conf file or e.g. the `recipes-images/images/your-image.bb` file or in a [packagegroup](https://git.phytec.de/meta-yogurt/tree/recipes-images/packagegroups/packagegroup-update.bb?h=master).  The first solution is the quick and dirty one.

Comment: After i try build some simple application using my own recipes i finally understand what you mean. Thanks

Comment: @KJ Lau The best introduction to Yocto I could find are these: https://bootlin.com/doc/training/yocto/yocto-slides.pdf

Answer (score 3):

`INHERIT += "image-buildinfo"` generates a `/etc/build` file and not `/etc/os-release` that you're looking for

See this [official section of mega-manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-image-buildinfo)

Comment: Hi i do added the following, kindly refer pastebin below https://pastebin.com/TNetLdkP . May i know how generate to /etc/os-release?

Comment: you need to add "os-release" package to your image target or add to your `local.conf` the string `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " os-release"`

Answer (score 1):

You can add it by following method
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "os-release lsb-release"

Comment: Yup, i have done it. I am not sure why the moderator  hided my answer. But yup the answer just configure it at local.conf.